# Spring: Passing modified command object to response page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a simple Spring 2.5 JSP form where I accept the zodiac sign of a user from a drop down list, validate that he has chosen a parameter and on form submission I call a utility method to get the forecast for the sign (random strings in fact for this test application).

But when I set it in the `ModelAttrribute` its not being passed to the response page. How can I pass the additional attribute to the response page?

My Model object is `Forecast`, with two attributes `ZodiacSign` and  `Forecast`. The following code is in controller that gets called on form submission:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("forecast") Forecast forecast, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status, ModelMap model) { 
    forecastFormValidator.validate(forecast, result); 
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        //if validator fails
        return "forecastForm";
    } 
    else {
        //the utility class, will set a random string as forecast
        //in the forecast attribute of forecast object and return the
        //modified object
        forecast = myUtil.returnForecastForZodiac(forecast);

        //Following prints the forecast string correctly
        System.out.println(forecast.getForecast());
    }                       

    status.setComplete();
    //form success
    return "forecastSuccess";
}
```

The `forecastSuccess` JSP simply displays the "forecast" model attributes (example: ${forecast.zodiacSign}), but it doesn't display the value of forecast attribute that I set in the method above (**in fact I modified the object itself**).

It seems the response form is passed the old object that the `forecastForm` provided it (with only the zodiac sign) and the manipulation I did in my method didn't affect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Spring. **You improperly used the `forecast` reference.**

This is the faulty code:

```
forecast = myUtil.returnForecastForZodiac(forecast);
```

The `forecast` reference now points to a a local object in your method, created by your util call. But the reference is a copy and thus the original object remains unchanged.

Once you exit the method you are back to the old value.

You must do a `forecast.setStuff(...)` and not `forecast = someStuff`. The first modifies the object, the second reassigns the reference leaving the original intact.

Remember that Java is always pass by value (even the reference is pass by value). [Further reading found here for an explanation of why assigning to object parameters doesn't always yield the expected result](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html).